# Can I create object in the same class?

Tags: c++, class, object, instance

Can I create an object of a class in the same class ?
If not what can I do ?

example stack class

```
template <class T>
class stack
{

void push(T d)
{
...
}

T pop()
{
...
}

//my question is about this one
void sort()
{
// I get errors when I do that ?
 stack st;
 st.push(4);
}

};
```

Comment: what do you want to do with your sort method? And if you want to use your class, you should create an instance of that class

Comment: `stack` needs to be instantiated with a type `stack<T> st;`

Comment: What errors were you getting?

Comment: What's the actual problem? Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902384/static-class-member-of-classs-own-type

Answer (score 1):

Without templates this is fine, e.g.

```
class stack
{
  public: //<-- added so we can use this
  void push(int d)
  {
  //...
  }

  int pop()
  {
  //...
  }

  void sort()
  {
    stack st;
    st.push(4);
  }
};
```

Now, in your templated case, you will <strike>need to</strike> can tell the sort function what kind of stack to make.

```
  void sort()
  {
    stack<T> st;
    //---^^^
    st.push(4);
  }
```

*more edit*
Section 14.6.1

> "The injected-class-name can be used with or without a
>   template-argument-list. When it is used without a
>   template-argument-list, it is equivalent to the injected-class-name
>   followed by the template-parameters of the class template enclosed in
>   <>."

So, you can say `stack st;`

You will not be able to have a member variable of type `stack<T>` though.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly OK to create an object of the same type inside a class. You should be able to get it to work with `stack<T>`, like this

```
template <class T>
class stack
{
    ...

    void sort()
    {
        stack<T> st;
        st.push(4);
    }

    ...
};
```

It seems that `stack st;` is correct according to the latest C++ standards, but maybe your compiler hasn't implemented this part of the C++ standard yet.

Having said that, it's not clear from your posted code why this is a template. If it were a template I'd expect to see

```
void push(const T& x)
{
    ...
}

T pop()
{
    ...
}
```

etc. Are you sure you want this to be a template? You should do that properly or not at all.

Comment: I'm wondering how the sort is going to try to swap itself with `st`

Comment: I think Section 14.6.1 means we are wrong, and it compiles ok without <T> on VS2012.

Comment: @doctorlove OK I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Im still new to the template so I writing code and compiling and it worked. May I ask why I need const T& x ?

Comment: @user2849898 Both `T` and `const T&` are correct. But by using `const T&` you avoid making an extra copy of T when you push something onto your stack. T could be anything, it might be something that is very inefficient to copy. So that's why in this kind of code it's better to use `const T&` for a function parameter.